# Stripe: Billing Address Validation

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to validate the billing address of the user. But I am unable to validate that, I have validate zipcode. In my php code I have set billingAddress  = true but still it is not verifying my billing address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe itself cannot check the ZIP or billing address - only the bank that issued the card can do so. If you supply a ZIP and/or billing address, Stripe will forward that information to the bank, which might or might not use it. It varies by country and by bank.

If you supply the ZIP and address and the results of the [`address_zip_check`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object-address_zip_check) and [`address_line1_check`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#card_object-address_line1_check) attributes is `unavailable`, that means the bank did not use the information that was provided.

Comment: Yes correct but on Stripe Dashboard screen there is an option to check for zipcode. A user cannot proceed for payment if he enters wrong zipcode. So I am able to validate zipcode but I am aunable to validate address even if I am entering incorrect address with correct zipcode my payment proceed with result "address_zip_check" and "address_line1_check" attributes is true/available.

Comment: "If you supply the ZIP and address...." How do you supply the address? I'm reading through https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/reference and haven't figured it out yet. Postal code is included in the tokenization, and the response references the address and existence of an address check, my form has an address input, but stripe doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add this for people wondering how to send the zip code in for validation.

```
 var options = {
    name: document.getElementById('name').value,
    address_line1: document.getElementById('address-line1').value,
    address_line2: document.getElementById('address-line2').value,
    address_city: document.getElementById('address-city').value,
    address_state: document.getElementById('address-state').value,
    address_zip: document.getElementById('address-zip').value,
    address_country: document.getElementById('address-country').value,
  };
  stripe.createToken(cardNumberElement, options).then(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Block if :address_line1_check: = 'fail'

This will make sure that the bank verifies that address on the card is accurate.

Comment: Is this an intended change in client code or in configuration at Stripe?

Comment: @JoelMeador This should be set on Stripe's Radar module in Dashboard